# If I explicitly break the 3-state Potts model $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, what changes at the phase transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

I'm hoping to understand generic features of systems that undergo a $\mathbb{Z}_3$-breaking phase transition. I've noticed that models that I usually associated with a $\mathbb{Z}_3$ symmetry, like the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ [clock model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_clock_model), actually have a larger $S_3$ symmetry. Does the difference between $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $S_3$ matter for the properties of the phase transition?

---

To make my question more concrete, I'd like to consider the classical $3$-state Potts model on the $2$d square lattice with a perturbation that breaks the $S_3$ symmetry down to $\mathbb{Z}_3$. I'll take the spins on the lattice to $\sigma_i \in \{1,2,3\}$ with Hamiltonian

$$H = - \sum_{\langle i j \rangle} \delta_{\sigma_i \sigma_j}+\lambda \sum_{\langle ijk \rangle} \delta_{\sigma_i 1}\delta_{\sigma_j 2}\delta_{\sigma_k 1}+\delta_{\sigma_i 2}\delta_{\sigma_j 3}\delta_{\sigma_k 2}+\delta_{\sigma_i 3}\delta_{\sigma_j 1}\delta_{\sigma_k 3}$$

Here, $\langle ij \rangle$ refer to nearest neighbors, and $\langle ijk \rangle$ correspond to three consecutive spins in a row or three consecutive spins in a column. The idea for the perturbation is that it's manifestly symmetric under the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ cyclic symmetry of $(1,2,3)\to(2, 3,1)$, but it breaks the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetries exchanging a pair of $(1,2,3)$, such as $(1,2) \to (2,1)$.

For $\lambda>0$ (the only case I'll consider), it's clear that the low temperature behavior should be somewhat similar to the Potts model. Like the Potts model, the model should become ordered, say with a dominance of $1$. Unlike the Potts model, it will be easier to have excitations of type $3$ rather than type $2$ within this symmetry-broken state with a predominance of $1$, since the perturbation penalizes the former, at least when the excitations are sparse. We can make analogous statements for the other symmetry-broken states. At large temperature, the system will be disordered.

Will the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ symmetry-breaking phase transition in this $\mathbb{Z}_3$ symmetric system be in the same universality class as that of the $S_3$-symmetric $3$-state Potts model? Equivalently, is the $\lambda$ perturbation relevant at the $3$-state Potts transition?

Comment: You could first try to find the spin configurations with the smallest energy. For small enough $\lambda$, you recover the 3 ferromagnetic phases. For $\lambda$ large, you get different ground states.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for the interest! For $\lambda>0$ at low temperatures, our aim will be to maximize the Potts term $\sum_{\langle i j \rangle} \delta_{\sigma_i \sigma_j}$ and minimize the term on $\lambda$. There isn't any frustration in doing this; in the ferromagnetic ground states, the Potts term is maximized, and the $\lambda$ terms are minimized, so the ferromagnetic ground states remain as ground states.